# NInject not resolving HomeController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4.7.2 project.  I use NInject (upated today to ) 3.3.4 to maintain dependencies.  I don't use the web.Common thing that NInject pushes.  I have, instead:

```
public static class ResolverConfig
{
    public static void RegisterResolver()
    {
        INinjectModule module = new MyModule();
        IResolutionRoot kernel = new StandardKernel(module);
        NinjectDependencyResolver resolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

Which is in the global.asax with:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ResolverConfig.RegisterResolver();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

The NinjectDependencyResolver is:

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver :
    NinjectDependencyScope,
    System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver,
    System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver
{
    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IResolutionRoot resolver) : base(resolver)
    {
    }

    public System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new NinjectDependencyScope(Resolver);
    }
}
```

I use the same resolver for Web Api and Web pages.  The NinjectDependencyScope:

```
public class NinjectDependencyScope: IDependencyScope
{
    public NinjectDependencyScope(IResolutionRoot resolver)
    {
        Resolver = resolver ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resolver));
    }

    protected IResolutionRoot Resolver { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        object instance = null;
        if (serviceType != null)
        {
            instance = Resolver.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        var all = serviceType != null ?
            Resolver.GetAll(serviceType) :
            new object[0];
        return all;
    }
```

This has all been working for me for some time.  Today I have a Home controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public HomeController(IFindTerminalState engine, IWriteSubscriptionRecord writer)
    {
        Engine = engine;
        Writer = writer;
    }

    private IFindTerminalState Engine { get; }
    private IWriteSubscriptionRecord Writer { get; }

    [Route("Home/Index/{email?}/{returnUrl?}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(...)
    {
        ....
    }

    ...
}
```

And I have a module:

```
public class MyModule: NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        ...
        Bind<IFindTerminalState>().To<FindTerminalState>();
        ...
        string subscriptionApi = ...
        Bind<IWriteSubscriptionRecord>()
            .To<WriteMySubscriptionRecord>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("subscriptionApi", subscriptionApi);
    }
}
```

Both services injected in the HomeController are in the module.  I fire up the website and navigate to ~/Home/Index/bob@example%2Ecom/example%2Ecom I get an exception that says "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."  This code has been working till now.  Any idea where the mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot.  The IWriteSubscriptionRecord service has a dependency itself, and I didn't notice it.  The Ninject module isn't complete yet.